# Azure Devops requiring password every time I push from local to remote repository

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

Relatively new git and azure-devops user here.

I am currently working on a project locally that I wish to push to my private azure-devops repository called 'Hello_World'.

So locally, I did the following:

```
git remote add origin https://dkennetz@dev.azure.com/dkennetz/Hello_World/_git/Hello_World
```

Then I wanted to push all my local code to the remote repo, so I simply did:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

and I was prompted:

```
[dkennetz@nodecn204  Hello_World]$ git push -u origin --all
Password for 'https://dkennetz@dev.azure.com':
```

Which is fine. I entered the token the first time and I thought all things would be handled accordingly for future pushes. I was wrong. Every time after this, I still have to enter my password for pushes.

I am doing this as a simple test case to try out azure-devops but I can see this becoming a serious issue if each user in a project has to enter username and password for CI/CD every time a user wants to push code to a repo.

I thought maybe I could add something to my config to handle this, but I am not sure.

If I run:

```
git config --list
```

I get (the space is because of code formatting issues):

```
user.name=Dennis Kennetz
user.email=funkyman@funky.org
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

`remote.origin.url=https://dkennetz@dev.azure.com/dkennetz/Hello_World/_git/Hello_World`

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this help?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=vsts

Comment: what kind of complaint is that? you shouldnt really store username\password. you should use certificate either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time on this, I have found a solution that works for me (although it stores your token in plain text in your git credentials).

prior to pushing to your repo, enter the following:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

This will store any usernames and passwords in your config for 3600 seconds before dumping. You can modify the time in timeout to the length of your session, or just leave off timeout for indefinite storage.

This way, you only have to type in your token once, and it will store until the time duration is reached, at which point you will have to type it again.